# How to get ID of record from one of the tables involved in a join

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm displaying a table of suppliers with their products.

```
$productID = $_POST['simplexID'];

$suppliers = "SELECT * FROM suppliers_products, suppliers WHERE supplier_id = suppliers.id AND our_simp_code = '$productID'";
$supplierProducts = mysqli_query($connect , $suppliers)or die(mysqli_error($connect));

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>Supplier</th><th>Pack Qty</th><th>Cost</th><th>Edit</th></tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($supplierProducts , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['pack_qty'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['cost'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo "<a href='editsupplierproduct.php?id=$id' >Edit</a>";
    echo "</td></tr>";      
}
echo "</table>";
```

As you see the last data field in the table is an `Edit` link that brings the user to a page to edit this record.

The thing is in the first line of the table loop I get the id of that row but my problem is that it doesn't know which table to grab the id from as I'm using a join.
How can I overcome this?

EDIT: Here's the edit product page

```
 //Get id of product being edited
        $editID= $_GET['id'];

        $editProduct = "SELECT * FROM suppliers_products WHERE id = $editID";
        $product = mysqli_query($connect , $editProduct)or die("Error retrieving data!");

        echo "<div class='editsupproduct'>";
            echo "<form method='post' action='updatesupplierproduct.php'>";

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($product , MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "Product Code: <input type='text' name='procode' value='" . $row['sup_product_code'] . "'><br>";
                    echo "Simplex Code: <input type='text' name='simcode' value='" . $row['our_simp_code'] . "'><br>";
                    echo "Pack Quantity: <input type='text' name='qty' value='" . $row['pack_qty'] . "'><br>";
                    echo "Cost: <input type='text' name='cost' value='" . $row['cost'] . "'>";
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='proid' value='$editID'>";
                }

                echo "<input type='submit' value='Update'>";
            echo "</form>";

            echo "<form method='post' action='deletesupplierproduct.php'>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='supproduct' value='$editID'>";
                echo "<input type='submit' value='Delete'>";
            echo "</form>";


        echo "</div>";
```

Comment: show code of **editsupplierproduct.php**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'id' must be unique, or SQL will throw a wobbly.

From your tables it looks like 'id' only exists in 'suppliers' - so it will be that one.

If you want a specific 'id' to be returned, then you can achieve this in the query:

```
SELECT suppliers_products.supplier_id as id,
       suppliers.* 
FROM suppliers_products, suppliers 
WHERE....
```

This will specifically return the 'supplier_id' from the 'suppliers_products' table, but aliased 'id'

Comment: I actually want to get 'id' field in the suppliers_products table, in that table there's also 'supplier_id'

Comment: This done the job...$suppliers = "SELECT suppliers_products.id as id, suppliers.*, suppliers_products.* FROM suppliers_products, suppliers WHERE supplier_id = suppliers.id AND our_simp_code = '$productID'"; Thanks